# Dynamic python properties

Tags: python, properties

Alright, I am rephrasing my question as my motivation wasn't clear enough.

We have a class that users will be populating with properties that are actually implemented using more complex storage/retrieval mechanisms.
I've simplified it below.
Assume the storage mechanism is just a simple dictionary for now:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.mydict = d

    def getterX(self):
        return self.mydict['X']
    def setterX(self, val):
        self.mydict['X'] = val
    X = property(getterX, setterX)

    def getterY(self):
        return self.mydict['Y']
    def setterY(self, val):
        self.mydict['Y'] = val
    Y = property(getterY, setterY)

da = {}
Ma = MyClass(da)

Ma.X = 5
Ma.Y = 6
print(Ma.X, Ma.Y)   #outputs 5 6
print(da)           #outputs {'Y': 6, 'X': 5}
```

This works fine, except its quite error prone and verbose.
It requires five lines with no less than **7** instances of **X** that needs to be cut+paste for each new property.
Some of these classes may have dozens of properties.

In lieu of using macros (which I don't think Python supports, and is inefficient), I'm trying to simplify this with some helper functions:

```
da = {}

class MyHelper:
    def __init__(self, dict, label):
        self.mydict = dict
        self.mylabel = label

    def getter2(self, other):
         return self.mydict[self.mylabel]

    def setter2(self, other, value):
        self.mydict[self.mylabel] = value

def makeProperty(d, label):
    H = MyHelper(d, label)
    return property(H.getter2, H.setter2)

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.mydict = d

    X = makeProperty(da, 'X')  #da is global, but should be self.mydict
    Y = makeProperty(da, 'Y')  #  " " "

Ma = MyClass(da)

Ma.X = 5
Ma.Y = 6
print(Ma.X, Ma.Y)   #outputs 5 6
print(da)           #outputs {'Y': 6, 'X': 5}
```

Now this *almost* works, except calls to **makeProperty()** need to access a global variable **da**, instead of using self member data.

This is where I'm stuck, but I'm inclined to believe its possible, given the first  code example accesses self member data in its getter/setters.

Hopefully this makes things more clear.
Thanks,
Rob.

Further information:

I think this solution will not work, as it appears the makeProperty calls are only called once, not once per class instantiation as I was assuming.

So is there any way to make this work, or is the user relegated to much cutting + pasting?

Comment: what exactly is y supposed to be?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do here. You can either have the class itself and assign it variables OR assign variables to the class instances. There is no way I can think of that will achieve this (because it doesnt make sense to me). Maybe if you explained in more detail what exactly you are trying to achieve, i could be of more help

Comment: A property that gets mirrored in a common repository for example.

Comment: addCustomProperty is undefined also im sure ... since I dont see that anywhere ...

Comment: I think you want `y` to be a method rather than a property, and the return value will be calculated **using** `self.scale`.

Comment: "Can instances of MyClass each have unique getter/setter functions for property y?"  No, assuming by "property" you mean a real Python [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: 'addCustomProperty' is not defined for brevity.

y could be a method, but our workflow will entail several such properties, and defining getter/setter methods for each is tedious and error prone.

Comment: Maybe a broader explanation of what you're trying to accomplish could lead to better suggestions.

Comment: So what do you expect the getter and setter for the 'generated' property to *be*? `return self.scale` and `self.scale = newvalue`? In which case, why not just do `self.y = scale` *instead*? You don't **need properties here** if all you are doing is returning or setting an *existing attribute*.

Comment: Im trying to get a unique getter and setter for each instance of MyClass. Though each instance of MyClass will have a 'y'.

Comment: You may want to explain *why you need to generate properties in the first place*.

Comment: @rbairos: you cannot have properties *per instance*, because properties are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), which **must** live on the class.

Comment: "@rbairos: you cannot have properties per instance, because properties are descriptors, which must live on the class"

I was hoping that the property itself (example 'y') could have its own data.

For example, it *is* legal for the getter and setter to be class members, which access self.scale no?

Comment: @rbairos: this sounds very much like you are trying to ask us to [pick between a shoe and a glass bottle](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925) here. Please *tell us the actual problem* you are trying to solve.

Comment: y is not a member, but access to a global storage we've set up.
Setting and getting y will involve quite a bit of processing I haven't included for brevity.

I *can* do this by having the getter and setter methods defined as members in the class, which access self, but Im hoping to use the single line equivalent above, as we will have several such properties defined.

Comment: So you want something like @property getters/setters but they just require too many lines of code for your taste?

Comment: @rbairos: please update your question with such details. There are ways to produce getters and setters that dynamically handle attributes, but you haven't given us *nearly enough detail*.

Comment: @rbairos: like, how do getters and setters vary between the various properties?

Comment: sorry, I need to step away, I'll update and clarify in a few hours..
Thanks for your input thus far.

Comment: Ive just rephrased the question entirely with working source code that hopefully explains my issue. Please let me know if this changes your responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the question "Can instances of MyClass each have unique getter/setter functions for property y?", the literal answer is "no" -- descriptors (including `property`) are looked up on the class, not on the instance.

However, class-level descriptors **can** delegate to instance-held callables, resulting in a similar effect.  Your example is not fully clear to me, but, consider for example:

```
class Whatever(object):

    def __init__(self, scale, getter=lambda x: 42):
        self.scale = scale
        self.getter = getter

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.getter(self.scale)

plain = Whatever(33)
fancy = Whatever(47, lambda x: x*2)
```

Now `plain.y` will be `42`, ignoring `plain.scale` even if that's changed; while `fancy.y` will initially be `94`, but change if and when `fancy.scale` changes.  Is that the kind of thing you're trying to do?  It would surely help to see desired use-cases...

Added: given we've seen a simplified use case in a big edit of the Q, here's how I would solve it:

```
class MyHelper:
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.mylabel = label

    def getter2(self, other):
        return other.mydict[self.mylabel]

    def setter2(self, other, value):
        other.mydict[self.mylabel] = value

def makeProperty(label):
    H = MyHelper(label)
    return property(H.getter2, H.setter2)

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.mydict = d

    X = makeProperty('X')
    Y = makeProperty('Y')
```

The factory-function `makeProperty` could be elided by changing the names of `MyHelper`'s methods to `__get__` and `__set__` (i.e, making `MyHelper` itself into a descriptor type) and calling `MyHelper` directly to build its instances to be assigned, but this slightly less direct approach may perhaps be easier to understand as it relies on the well-known built-in type `property`.

Comment: Hi I've rephrased my question entirely above for clarity.
I'm not certain if your information is still applicable.
Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes thank you, it occurred to me this morning, I did not need to pass in self to makeProperty, as it would be available as the 'other' argument in the getter/setter calls.
Thank you for confirming and providing extra explanation.